# Detecting how a mdi child is closed

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a mdi application with multiple child windows.

There are 3 ways of closing a child window.

When I close an individual child using X, the `CloseReason` is `UserClosing`.

When I close the application the `CloseReason` is `MdiFormClosing`.

When I click a menu item on the main form which I have programmed to close all child windows, leaving the main form open, the `CloseReason` is `UserClosing`.

However, I want the behaviour to be the different only when I close an individual child using X. Any suggestions?

Comment: You cannot tinker with the e.CloseReason, that's hard-baked into Winforms.  Simply set a public *bool* property to true in your MDI parent when menu item Click event handler starts closing child windows.  You can get its value in the MDI child's FormClosing event handler.